# Integrate kayako and tfs

Tags: tfs

I am in need of replicating all kayako helpdesk tickets into TFS. This includes creation of the ticket, updates of the ticket, and closure of the ticket. I've looked around and I can't seem to find any elegant solution to this. Can any of you point me int he right direction?

Comment: What sort of API does kayako have?

Comment: The rest api http://wiki.kayako.com/display/DEV/Kayako+REST+API Which is something I've never worked with

Answer (score 1):

You can roll your own integration by building on the [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Does Kayako support webhooks? webhooks allow you to send data when it happens, so for example when a ticket is created or when it is resolved - you can then have your application process that data. This is far better than having to make repeated calls to an API to see if there are changes to a system.

Comment: It does have a concept of hooks and ability to run custom code http://wiki.kayako.com/display/DEV/Directory+of+Existing+Hook+Locations  I imagine staff_ticket_edit could work for this purpose.